# Stop Prompting to use Google or Safari

Tags: google, safari

Every time I go to the web on my iPhone 6 it asks me if I want to use Google or Safari. Every time I select the option to not ask me every time but it still does. I have designated Safari as my primary web app in settings.  Help please.

Comment: If you have dedicated Safari as your default web browser why not uninstall Google Chrome? Safari is highly optimised to run on iOS devices and comes with all the same features as Chrome. Just go with Safari.

Comment: Good advice. Makes sense. Thanks. I’ve had a gmail account for a long while that I would like to keep using. Also, once in a while I need to use Google Docs. I hope I will still be able to access them after removing Google Chrome. I’ll give it a try.